# even after 0.0005BTC Fee, My transaction is unconfirmed

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made a transaction of approx 1 bTC.
MT transaction id is 
https://blockchain.info/tx/44f8a9939776bac1b98dffb4fe72d5ad97f3b2171c3b717677e9ae03b6bcef4d

but it is still unconfirmed even after the 0.0005 Fee.

Comment: now it is confirmed

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use fixed fees! Fees are not per transaction, they are per byte (size of the transaction matters).**

The size of the transaction is based on how many inputs you use. Mostly, that's not under your control.

You transaction above is 815bytes.
You fee: 0.0005 0BTC.
~= 0.000613 BTC/bytes

The current feerate to get confirmed within the next 10 blocks is 0.00136386/1000bytes (March 8th 2017).

Your fee is way to low to compete with other transactions.